# What is a good light-weight CSV viewer?

Tags: windows

Are there any good lightweight CSV viewers out there? I would like something that easily refreshes a file after it has been modified. A quick google search didn't turn up any clear winners.

I'd prefer not to have to open Excel each time since it locks the file. This prevents any other programs from updating the file.

Comment: This seems like a cool project, can the viewer be readonly?

Comment: Just use a basic text editor eg notepad++

Answer (score 131):

This is for viewing only, using Powershell...

GUI Display; supports sorting, filtering:

```
    Import-Csv yourfile.csv |Out-GridView
```

Console Display:

```
    Import-Csv yourfile.csv |Format-Table -AutoSize
```

or:

```
    Import-Csv yourfile.csv |Format-List
```

For additional sorting and filtering options, pipe through where-object and sort-object cmdlets

Comment: Is there a vertical column format?

Comment: That was AWESOME. One thing to note though, if you want to specify the delimiter (for not-so-much-comma separated values) use `-delimiter ';'`

Comment: Is there anyway I can automate this from Windows Explorer or from the right click menu?

Comment: This is wonderful, it even recognizes tab-separated files automatically. Not even excel does that...

Comment: It's closed, but I find it awesome

Answer (score 30):

I use Nirsoft's [CSVFileView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/csv_file_view.html). It is a simple lightweight read-only csv viewer.

Note: due to password recovery tools on Nirsoft's site many [virus checkers will block executables](https://www.nirsoft.net/false_positive_report.html) downloaded from there.

Comment: This does exactly what you want. Lightweight, but rich with options. One you'll want is Auto-refresh (and maybe partial refresh). Filters can help you see only the data you're interested in. A very useful tool.

Comment: The Nirsoft site is chock-full of great tools

Comment: There is also https://csviewer.com/

Answer (score 21):

If your system has Cygwin, `column -t` in a terminal window is what I like to use.

```
$ cat file.csv
1,2,3,4
A,B,C,D
i,ii,iii,iv,v
foo,bar,foo foo,foobar
No commas

$ column -t -s"," file.csv
1          2    3        4
A          B    C        D
i          ii   iii      iv      v
foo        bar  foo foo  foobar
No commas
```

In order to update with changes to the original as you requested, you can combine it with the `watch` command:

```
watch column -t -s, file.csv
```

Comment: Although the question is tagged **Windows**, `column -t` also appears on various flavors of *nix, including Mac OS, so please enjoy your ⬆ as much as I enjoyed your answer.

Answer (score 12):

These threads both point to [**CSVed**](https://csved.sjfrancke.nl/):

- [Light text editor for CSV file?](https://superuser.com/questions/119655/light-text-editor-for-csv-file-on-windows)
- [Looking for a very fast to load lightweight csv viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/173217/looking-for-a-very-fast-to-load-lightweight-csv-viewer)

I tried it and had some issues with larger files (4000000 rows) with lots of columns (313), so YMMV.

I usually just use the BSD column utility. It's part of the [**util-linux**](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux) package on windows:

Answer (score 8):

You could try [Ron's Editor](http://www.ronsplace.eu/Products/RonsEditor) - it will do what you want, is MUCH better than Excel for editing CSV files IMHO (that's why I wrote it), and I will let you decide if its light enough ;-)

Comment: Nice tool....  may have to purchase that!

Comment: Waaaay too expensive for personal needs

Answer (score 3):

Beacuse I was unhappy with how Excel displays CSV files, I produced a small executable designed to display CSV files. I recently made it available at http://csvquickviewer.com/
It’s only available for Windows because its writing in .NET

It does not need configuration but allows filtering, searching etc.

Comment: are you talking about this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/csvquickviewer/ as your link is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally find one can instantly open large files, and automatically detect the delimiter: The V File Viewer from  http://www.fileviewer.com/  20 days free trial. $20 to buy.

Another one, which is extremely fast and also automatically detect the delimiter is Delimit from http://delimitware.com 15 days free trail. $49 / year. Kind of expensive.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there are Free excel viewers out there on Microsoft's site.  And I think the native wordpad/write can also open up CSV files.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to look at the file, why not use a text editor?  The better ones will notice a refresh and prompt you if you want to reload the file.  However, they won't separate the values out into different columns for you; they will only display the contents.  Both UltraEdit and TextPad have been reliable for me in the past.

Comment: Text editors won't format the columns nicely. It would also be nice to have some simple functions built-in like SUM().

Answer (score -1):

OKFN's [DataPipes SaaS Tool](http://datapipes.okfnlabs.org/csv/) is an option for using in-browser.
GitHub automagically renders CSV into tables, providing another in-browser option, along with more functionality.