# Open a file with a PowerShell script in explorer

Tags: powershell, explorer

I wanted to use Windows built-in table viewer to open CSV file, like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32766651) shows.

So I want that when I double click on a CSV file in Explorer, the following command is run:

`Import-Csv [CSV-FILE] |Out-GridView`

I ended up creating two script files. One file name "read_csv.bat" which contains:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noexit -File %~dp0read_csv.ps1 -csvfile %1
pause
```

Another file name "read_csv.ps1" which contains the actual script

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$csvfile
 )

Import-Csv $csvfile |Out-GridView
```

Is there now way to do it more efficiently, so with only one script file? If I set explorer to open the CSV file with the POwerShell script directly, a blue message appears

> This app can't run on your PC
>   To find a version for your PC, check with your published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- Since `powershell.exe` is ultimately called, a ***console window* will invariably (also) open** when a CSV file is opened, because `powershell.exe` is a console-subsystem application.
- Providing an alternative, GUI-subsystem executable to avoid creating a console window is the subject of [this feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028); in the meantime, there are *workarounds*:

  - A VBScript-based solution is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41229169/45375).
  - A script-less, but complex and potentially AV-software-triggering alternative is used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064713/45375).

---

You'll need to **use an adapted version of the `powershell.exe` command from your batch file**, because **`*.ps1` files are by design *not directly executable***.

That is, in the registry definition for the CSV file type, use the following command to define the action for the `Open` verb (see below):

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -File c:\path\to\read_csv.ps1 -csvfile "%1"
```

Be sure to substitute the real path to your `*.ps1` script for `c:\path\to\read_csv.ps1` (double-quote it, if necessary); you can either use a literal path, or one based on `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references (e.g., `"%USERPROFILE%\read_csv.ps1"`).

Alternatively, you can **make do without a script file altogether**, **using the PowerShell CLI's 
`-Command` parameter**:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command Import-Csv \"%1\" | Out-GridView
```

---

To **automate the process of configuring** this command for opening CSV files via File Explorer / the desktop:

The code below modifies the registry as follows:

- defines a new file type, `PsCsvViewer`, with an `Open` verb (operation) that invokes the PowerShell command defined above.
- associates the `.csv` filename extension with that new file type.

  - Note: The first time you open a CSV file after the redefinition, you may be prompted to confirm the intent to use a PowerShell command from now on.
- creates the definitions above for the *current user only*, which means that you don't need admin privileges to run the code (which writing to subkeys of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\` would require).

```bsh
# Note the need for *3* "\", because an extra layer of escaping is
# needed for reg.exe.
$cmd = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command Import-Csv \\\"%1\\\" | Out-GridView'

# Create a new file type for the PowerShell command.
reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Classes\PsCsvViewer\Shell\Open\command /ve /d $cmd  /f

# Associate .csv files with the new file type.
reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Classes\.csv /ve /d PsCsvViewer /f
```